# Match cell arrays with different size based on two conditions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, size, match, cell

`RECCELL` is a cell array with 8 columns and 30000 rows:

```
 C1     C2      C3          C4   C5          C6     C7    C8
'AA'    1997    19970102    1   'BACHE'     'MORI'  148   127
'AA'    1997    19970108    2   'MORGAN'     []     1595  0
'AA'    1997    19970224    3   'KEMSEC'    'FATHI' 1315  297
```

`CONCELL` is a cell array with 4 columns and 70000 rows:

```
 C1     C2      D3          D4
'AA'    1997    19970116    2,75
'AA'    1997    19970220    2,71
'AA'    1997    19970320    2,61
```

I would like to **add** to `RECCELL` the 4 columns of `CONCELL` only in case the `C1s` match and `C3` and `D3` (both dates) are **the closest** possible. For instance I would get in this example:

```
 C1     C2      C3         C4    C5           C6     C7    C8   C1      C2      D3          D4           

'AA'    1997    19970102    1   'BACHE'      'MORI'  148   127  'AA'    1997    19970116    2,75

'AA'    1997    19970108    2   'MORGAN'     []      1595  0    'AA'    1997    19970116    2,75

'AA'    1997    19970113    3   'KEMSEC'    'FATHI'  1315  297  'AA'    1997    19970220    2,71
```

- To the **first** row of RECCELL corresponds the **first** row of CONCELL.
- To the **second** row of RECCELL corresponds the **first** row of CONCELL.
- To the **third** row of RECCELL corresponds the **second** row of CONCELL.

The code I have so far is:

```
[~, indCon, indREC] = intersect(CONCELL(:,1), RECCELL(:,1));
REC_CON=[RECCELL(indREC,:),CONCELL(indCon,:)];
NO_REC_CON= RECCELL(setdiff(1:size(RECCELL,1), indREC),:);
```

It's wrong because I cannot use `intersect` for a string element and because I am not considering the second condition, which is to choose the closest dates.

Can someone help me? Thank you

Comment: One question to see if I got your question right: Basically you want to find for each row of `RECCELL` the row of `CONCELL` which has the same first element and which has the least distance between the 4th elements right? and another question are your matrices sorted? and if so sorted for the time (C3) or C1?

Comment: @TheMinion for each row of `RECCELL` the row of `CONCELL` which has the same first element and which has the least distance between the **3RD** elements (the dates)

Comment: @TheMinion they are first sorted by C1. But for all the same C1s they automatically get so to say a 'second sorting' by date.        `[~, con] = sort(CONCELL(:,1));
    CONCELL = CONCELL(con,:);   
[~, rec] = sort(RECCELL(:,1));
    RECCELL = RECCELL(rec,:);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to do this inside a for loop as the cells are very tall.
(Note: it seems like the date format (C3/D3) in the cell is a double opposed to a string, thus needs to be converted first for using [datenum](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html))

```
n=size(RECCELL,1);
ind=zeros(n,1);
rd=datenum(num2str(cell2mat(CONCELL(:,3))),'yyyymmdd'); % convert double to string
for k=1:n
    a=find(ismember(CONCELL(:,1),RECCELL(k,1))==1);     % find indices of matching C1s
    if ~isempty(a)                                      % do only if there is a match for the C1s
        dnk=datenum(num2str(RECCELL{k,3}),'yyyymmdd');  % convert double to string
        [~,f]=min((rd(a)-dnk).^2);                      % find closest date of the subset a
        ind(k,1)=a(f);                                  % assign index of closest match to ind
        RECCELL(k,(end+1):(end+4))=CONCELL(ind(k,1),:); % add CONCELL to RECCELL, be aware that other rows will now display empty cells, and a row of RECCELL can keep 'growing'
    end
end
```

The vector `ind` contains the indices of the closest match in `CONCELL` for each entry in `RECCELL`. When it contains a 0, no match was found between the `C1`s.

Edit: One possible solution to avoid increasing the number of columns of `RECCELL` if multiple `CONCELL` entries are added to the same `RECCELL` entry is the following which results in a adding a single column to the RECCELL matrix:

```
n=size(RECCELL,1);
RECCELL{1,end+1}=[];                                    % to add a single empty column to RECCELL
ind=zeros(n,1);
rd=datenum(num2str(cell2mat(CONCELL(:,3))),'yyyymmdd'); % convert double to string
for k=1:n
    a=find(ismember(CONCELL(:,1),RECCELL(k,1))==1);     % find indices of matching C1s
    if ~isempty(a)                                      % do only if there is a match for the C1s
        dnk=datenum(num2str(RECCELL{k,3}),'yyyymmdd');  % convert double to string
        [~,f]=min((rd(a)-dnk).^2);                      % find closest date of the subset a
        ind(k,1)=a(f);                                  % assign index of closest match to ind
        if isempty(RECCELL{k,end})                      % if nothing is in this cell, add the CONCELL entry to it
            RECCELL{k,end}=CONCELL(ind(k,1),:);
        else                                            % if something is already in, add the new CONCELL entry to the cell
            RECCELL{k,end}(end+1,1:4)=CONCELL(ind(k,1),:);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I am sorry, when you convert the date from double to string, shouldn't it be column 3 instead of 2? Column 2 only has the year and is not relevant for the match I guess. Am I wrong?

Comment: The code works, but how do I get to add the 4 columns of `CONCELL` to `RECCELL`? Thank you